# What would i put in buttonClicked() to call a scene on swift IOS

Tags: swift, swift-playground

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWn2e.png)

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDEyk.png)

I am trying to make a button that calls GameScene1 and is in GameScene.
What would I have to put in the buttonClicked part so that I can do this? I am writing the code on the IOS version of swift

Comment: Add the code instead of a pic of the code.